# ArchUnit Rule to prevent access to derived classes?

Tags: archunit

A colleague did some refactoring and moved a method to a superclass to be able to reuse it from an other child-class, too. The IDE handled that quickly and without any complains.
That method, however, internally referred to a constant which was *not* moved with the method, i.e. the parent class thus now referred to a constant in one of its child-classes which of course is a no-no!

How can I phrase an ArchUnit rule that prevents such references from parent to members/methods/local classes and enums/etc. in child-classes (or in general: anything in classes further down the hierarchy)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For direct dependencies, you can use the following custom [`ArchCondition`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/latest/com/tngtech/archunit/lang/ArchCondition.html):

```java
@ArchTest
ArchRule rule = noClasses().should(new ArchCondition<JavaClass>("depend on their children") {
    @Override
    public void check(JavaClass parentClass, ConditionEvents events) {
        parentClass.getDirectDependenciesFromSelf().stream()
            .filter(dependency -> dependency.getTargetClass() != parentClass
                    && dependency.getTargetClass().isAssignableTo(parentClass.getName()))
            .forEach(dependency -> events.add(satisfied(dependency, dependency.getDescription())));
    }
});
```

It can easily be adapted to also catch transitive dependencies such as in this example:

```java
class Parent { 
    Friend friend; 
}
class Friend { 
    Child child; 
}
class Child extends Parent { 
}
```

You can basically replace [`getDirectDependenciesFromSelf`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/latest/com/tngtech/archunit/core/domain/JavaClass.html#getDirectDependenciesFromSelf()) with [`getTransitiveDependenciesFromSelf`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/latest/com/tngtech/archunit/core/domain/JavaClass.html#getTransitiveDependenciesFromSelf()):

```java
@ArchTest
ArchRule rule = noClasses().should(new ArchCondition<JavaClass>("depend on their children") {
    @Override
    public void check(JavaClass parentClass, ConditionEvents events) {
        parentClass.getTransitiveDependenciesFromSelf().stream()
            .filter(dependency -> dependency.getTargetClass() != parentClass
                    && dependency.getTargetClass().isAssignableTo(parentClass.getName()))
            .forEach(dependency -> events.add(satisfied(dependency, parentClass.getName()
                    + " (transitively) depends on its child: " + dependency.getDescription())));
    }
});
```

FYI: I'm using the following static imports:

```java
import static com.tngtech.archunit.lang.SimpleConditionEvent.satisfied;
import static com.tngtech.archunit.lang.syntax.ArchRuleDefinition.noClasses;
```

Comment: Perfect solution - worked like a charm! Thanks a lot!
And - oh boy - it found quite number of similar cases in our code. Will take me a while to analyze and fix all these!

Comment: To be honest, I also threw it on my code base and also found quite some. I didn't have the time to look into it yet, but I feel that the rule could have false positives I don't understand yet, e.g. `enum FamousNumber { ONE{}, TWO{} }`.

Comment: Thanks for continuing on this. I had a similar impression when looking at the results from the `getTransitiveDependenciesFromSelf`-variant. There was quite a list which I can't imagine to be all true. But I also had several hits using `getDirectDependenciesFromSelf` already which - on first sight at least - looked correct, so I'll investigate (and possibly fix) these first. And then I'll try to figure out why the other variant detected that many cases and if these are indeed valid.